# Developer Authenticated Identities with Amazon

Tags: ios, authentication, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm not familar very well with Amazon so have few questions:

I want to perform login for users on amazon with Cognito using my own custom backEnd solution. Found [this](https://github.com/danilop/LambdAuth) like possible solution. This backEnd return after registering and logging for me

```
{
    identityId = "eu-xxxx-x:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx";
    login = 1;
    token = "eyJraWQiOiJldS13ZXN0LTExIiwidHlwIjoiSldTIiwiYWxnIjoiUlM1MTIifQ.eyJzdWIiOiJldS13ZXN0LTE6NGFmNDdmMWItZDNmOC00NmZkLWI2MzEtZGE2OGU3ZmRmYzE1IiwiYXVkIjoiZXUtd2VzdC0xOjIwNjBiZDc3LWEwNDAtNGI4OC05MDU4LTczMGY3Y2RmNGQyZSIsImFtciI6WyJhdXRoZW50aWNhdGVkIiwibG9naW4ud3A0Lm15YXBwIiwibG9naW4ud3A0Lm15YXBwOmV1LXdlc3QtMToyMDYwYmQ3Ny1hMDQwLTRiODgtOTA1OC03MzBmN2NkZjRkMmU6a2lyaWxsLmdlQGdtYWlsLmNvbSJdLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2NvZ25pdG8taWRlbnRpdHkuYW1hem9uYXdzLmNvbSIsImV4cCI6MTQ1NTI5MDA5OSwiaWF0IjoxNDU1Mjg5MTk5fQ.FGnBUEQZ3wDENFNa_g29l2UhlIAklBnLdqpMomSE3_ayesNV1dqGyzAMQCvwyr4XdJpB3lI0KF-k3wc4t8BKPYg5QKrZ-q-aNkjwp34tHFMIr8vGw4vbZiKB6XnGMRghYSbPtuwwFG80ibZMAAXik4nld8sGxoQSrCjTubPKU4I9Mzi6lJQsDGAZxmm56E2lVSeBw2nZbE1iwRDhJf6hHJsKOLceDDtWoknRX3NHeNuoueNLS1JrbphD8wVqejxhEjrK-qucoUL_uj81GxYUkyONQtu-3B79epsXIsxvU_zW1MwVufFg5p5ID83F1Cic77QkzF2FJnEJIadEG6R_yw";
}
```

I want follow this [guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/). But according to this i should provide `IdentityProviderName` and token and set it like after any social's login :

```
credentialsProvider.logins = @{
    @(AWSCognitoLoginProviderKeyFacebook): token
};
```

As `IdentityProviderName` i used name that was setted in `config.json`

```
"DEVELOPER_PROVIDER_NAME": "<ProviderName>"
```

But i got exception that i havent any provider

> AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider
>   getCredentialsWithCognito:authenticated:]_block_invoke |
>   GetCredentialsForIdentity failed. Error is [Error
>   Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=8 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={__type=InvalidParameterException, message=Please provide a
>   valid public provider}]

When i go to IAM Console to create providerID it ask me to choose type of provider (OpenID or SAML)

[image]

So i'm really dont understand what exactly should i put there? what type to select.

For server i used Lambda service with DynamoDB service, for web pages used S3.

According to [this](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3E3NJURV1LNV1/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-using-developer-authenticated-identities-An-end-to-en) flow:

[image]

I already complete first 4 steps and i'm stack on 5 step, So i need only to send this data to Cognito (no needs to prepare my custom dev provider, because i already have idendityID and token, thats looks like incorrect).

As result

[image]

developer Auth - only for login method from lambda but when i try to use DynamoDB user are not auth.

All roles are added - currently i add temp role for Unath users

```
 {
        "Sid": "DynamoDBPolicy",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "dynamodb:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
```

All works (huh) but it's not really good

Question - how to make Cognito DevAuth with received token from my backEnd solution placed on Lambda? Does i miss something?

UPDATE

---

thanks to @Rachit Dhall

```
AWSCognitoIdentity *cognitoIdentity = [AWSCognitoIdentity defaultCognitoIdentity];
AWSCognitoIdentityGetCredentialsForIdentityInput *input = [[AWSCognitoIdentityGetCredentialsForIdentityInput alloc] init];
input.identityId = [task.result valueForKey:@"identityId"];
input.logins = @{
                 @"cognito-identity.amazonaws.com" : [task.result valueForKey:@"token"]
                 };

[cognitoIdentity getCredentialsForIdentity:input completionHandler:^(AWSCognitoIdentityGetCredentialsForIdentityResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

            //how to update my configuration for AWS with 
            //AWSCognitoIdentityCredentials object?
        }];
```

but not sure what to do with `AWSCognitoIdentityCredentials` received in response - how to update my configuration?

Also found next:

[image]

Does it mean that there is no another way for this? Or something missed?

Answer (score 4):

The error which says present a valid public provider issue, is because you are calling GetCredentialsForIdentity with your login provider. But instead the flow is that you call GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity from your backend, you get a token as response. Then to get credentials you call GetCredentialsForIdentity with key cognito-identity.amazonaws.com in the logins parameter and value as the token received from previous call.

Update:

To make sure Amazon DynamoDB [uses credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/accessing-aws-services.html) vended by Amazon Cognito you can create a default AWSServiceConfiguration with your credentials provider and use this to initialize the client.

```
// create a configuration that uses the provider
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 provider:credentialsProvider];

// get a client with the default service configuration
AWSDynamoDB *dynamoDB = [AWSDynamoDB defaultDynamoDB];
```

Comment: What are you storing in DynamoDB?

Comment: Ub DynamoDB currently i stored information about all users, and later i planned to add info about user devices, rooms, houses, topology, etc. I also think about Datasets from Cognito, but it's not actually what we need

Comment: So you can limit the access for your users to only their data by following this blog post [https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1OSMBRHZVM9V0/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-3-Roles-and-Policies]. For this you would need to have the hash key of DynamoDB table as the identityId.
We do not recommend storing data for unauthenticated users as if the identityId is lost on the device, there is no way to get that user's data again. If you are using developer authenticated identities, then you should be safe, but please be careful about storing data about unauthenticated users.

Comment: Thanks but can u advice what i should to do with received response with session token mean object of class AwscognitoidebtityCredentials - i guess i should to ipdate my service configuration somehow with it but how? Cant figure it out

Comment: Also i want to make shure that cognito interpret any requests for dynamodb as request from authuser (after user logging with my backend and i requested this session token from cognito) in this case think i shoud update with receives tokens my system configuration for amazon and dynamodbobjectmappet but i cant found a way to do this

Comment: Thanks a lot! so first request is to getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity with Logins key set to your defined developer entity name, and second request to getCredentialsForIdentity with Logins key set to cognito-identity.amazonaws.com as you've mentioned!